# How to count a change of number in a matrix in R?

Tags: r

I've a matrix called 'cmat':

```
> cmat
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    0
 [4,]    1
 [5,]    0
 [6,]    1
 [7,]    0
 [8,]    1
 [9,]    0
[10,]    1
[11,]    1
[12,]    1
[13,]    0
[14,]    0
[15,]    1
[16,]    0
[17,]    1
[18,]    0
[19,]    0
[20,]    1
[21,]    0
[22,]    1
[23,]    0
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is I want to count the number of times the value has become 1 from a previous value of 0. How to do this in R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sum(diff(cmat)==1)` might be a way to do it if there are only binary values.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
sum( cmat[, 1] == 1 & c(NA, head(cmat[, 1], -1)) == 0 , na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked for the matrix.. Could you please tell me how to achieve the same for a numeric vector instead of a matrix??

Comment: @KrishnaKanth just change `cmat[, 1]` to the name of your vector.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an alternative here.
`rle(cmat)` will let you identify every location at which  the  value changes as well as the new value.